# Hudson Emma Plug-in

Tags: java, continuous-integration, hudson, code-coverage, emma

Emma's Hudson plug-in is not generating the coverage.xml file! Where is it? I'm leaving the 'Folders or files containing Emma XML reports' blank so emma searches for the file, but the file is not being generated :(

Answer (score 1):

The Emma Hudson plugin does not generate `coverage.xml`.  It processes, displays, and  maintains statistics for `coverage.xml` files generated by your build script.

See the Emma documentation for how to integrate Emma into [ANT](http://emma.sourceforge.net/userguide/ar01s03.html) or [Maven](http://emma.sourceforge.net/maven-emma-plugin/) scripts.

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1: Was there an Error?

Emma may be throwing an error.

1. Go to the job that failed -> Console Output -> Full log.
2. Try to find:

> Emma: looking for coverage reports in the provided path:
>
> OR
>
> Emma: no coverage files found in workspace. Was any report generated?

Obviously troubleshoot as necessary if you find an exception.

### Step 2: Did you configure EMMA to create a coverage report?

1. Check the box, "Record Emma coverage report"
2. Enter path to the file.  Try "**/emma/coverage.xml"
3. Leave the Health reporting fields blank for defaults (for now, change it once it's working).